# Want to change audio input device for remote stream in webrtc

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webrtc

On my android chrome browser, I do not know that how to change audio output(mike to speaker and vice versa), I am building a webrtc app, and I have researched that we can change speaker by setSinkId but this does not support android Chrome according to mdn, this is the code I am using for changing deviceId.

```
    await audio.setSinkId(audioDevice[coun.current].deviceId);

const audioContext = new AudioContext({ sinkId: { type: 'none' } });
```

**Is there is any way to achieve this on android chrome on remote stream**